# Set the title dynamically in react native paper card title

Tags: react-native

I am using react native paper. But I have some trouble with setting the title with my variables. Any help is appreciated.

As stated in their doc `Text for the title. Note that this will only accept a string or <Text>-based node.` but I am not sure how to insert -based nodes
https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/components/Card/CardTitle

```
        <Card.Title
          title={
            <Text>
              Top {sites.length} Sights in {country.name}
            </Text>
          }
            />
```

But i get the following error

```
Text' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'Text' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'Text' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': render, context, setState, forceUpdate, and 3 more.
```

Comment: Eloborate the problem, The question is incomplete. If getting error please show the error or output snap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error appeares because title prop is expecting a text not JSX. To use variable title you can use this code

```
<Card.Title
          title={`Top ${sites.length} Sights in ${country.name}`}
/>
```

Comment: I tried to use jsx becasue I wanted to add a icon after the text. Is there a way that i can achieve that as well?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you confused [`Text`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text) from `react-native` with [`Text`](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/components/Text/) from `react-native-paper`.

With following code

```
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { Card, Text as PaperText } from 'react-native-paper'
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons'
...
  <Card.Title
    title={
      <PaperText>
        paper text with icon <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" size={24} color="white" />
      </PaperText>
    }
  />
```

I managed to create the card with icon in its title